# How to change background image to another upon hovering over button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have five buttons on one image.  Every time you hover over each button, I would like the background image to change according to each button you hover.  I tried doing this using CSS, but this doesn't seem to be very effective when applying the "hover" effect.  It only works if you hover over the background itself and it will change, but not when you hover over a button.

And if I tried applying the CSS "hover" effect by adding a class in the *li* section and a sort of image sprite just under the primary background image, the image would only appear within the *li* itself and not as a background cover.

I figured jQuery/javascript would be better.  But, I'm not sure how to apply what I would like.  I tried to do a hover action with javascript, but I'm not sure why it isn't working.  The following code is snippet from the main code on JSFiddle. Does anyone have suggestions?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Preload
  $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/nxs-kxantv-media-us-east-1/photo/2016/03/21/image-jpeg237_35345271_ver1.0_640_360.jpg').load(function() {
    $('#primary').append($(this));
  });

  $('#screenprinting').hover(function() {
    $('#primary').css('background-image', 'url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/nxs-kxantv-media-us-east-1/photo/2016/03/21/image-jpeg237_35345271_ver1.0_640_360.jpg")');
  }, function() {
    $('#primary').css('background', '');
  });
});
```

```css
#mma #primary.hp {
  background-image: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_423a4fd973804ba7b9f918a46481616b~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1567,h_611,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_423a4fd973804ba7b9f918a46481616b~mv2.jpg);
  background-position: 43% top
}
```

```html
<div id="mma" data-trackingposition="mma">
  <div id="primary" class="hp clearfix" data-speed="6" data-type="background">

    <div class="bucket">
      <p style="color:white;">Insure the things you love most...</p>
      <p class="title" style="color:white">Select a policy to get a quote</p>

      <span id="productheader" role="heading">asdf</span>

      <ul class="iconlist">
        <li class="attached check" data-prod="au">

          <span><a id="screenprinting" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Auto insurance" style="color:white;"><small><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_a3a5ee1aa8d6493abf7e20d1088719d7~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png/v1/fill/w_600,h_600,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_a3a5ee1aa8d6493abf7e20d1088719d7~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png" class="insurance-img"></small>Auto</a></span>

        </li>
        <li class="attached property" data-prod="ho">
          <span><a href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Home & Renters insurance" style="color:white;"><small><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_141f12dd5fc848b08fe41f79eded1260~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png/v1/fill/w_600,h_600,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_141f12dd5fc848b08fe41f79eded1260~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png" class="insurance-img"></small>Home </a></span>
          <span class="icon close"><a href="#" aria-label="Collapse Home & Renters" role="button">&#xe137;</a></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import jQuery library to make things work in jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Preload
  $('<img/>').hide().attr('src', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/nxs-kxantv-media-us-east-1/photo/2016/03/21/image-jpeg237_35345271_ver1.0_640_360.jpg').load(function() {
    $('#primary').append($(this));
  });

  $('#screenprinting').hover(function() {
    $('#primary').css('background-image', 'url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/nxs-kxantv-media-us-east-1/photo/2016/03/21/image-jpeg237_35345271_ver1.0_640_360.jpg")');
  }, function() {
    $('#primary').css('background', '');
  });
});
```

```css
#mma #primary.hp {
  background-image: url(https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_423a4fd973804ba7b9f918a46481616b~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1567,h_611,al_c,q_85,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_423a4fd973804ba7b9f918a46481616b~mv2.jpg);
  background-position: 43% top
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mma" data-trackingposition="mma">
  <div id="primary" class="hp clearfix" data-speed="6" data-type="background">

    <div class="bucket">
      <p style="color:white;">Insure the things you love most...</p>
      <p class="title" style="color:white">Select a policy to get a quote</p>

      <span id="productheader" role="heading">asdf</span>

      <ul class="iconlist">
        <li class="attached check" data-prod="au">

          <span><a id="screenprinting" href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Auto insurance" style="color:white;"><small><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_a3a5ee1aa8d6493abf7e20d1088719d7~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png/v1/fill/w_600,h_600,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_a3a5ee1aa8d6493abf7e20d1088719d7~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png" class="insurance-img"></small>Auto</a></span>

        </li>
        <li class="attached property" data-prod="ho">
          <span><a href="#" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Home & Renters insurance" style="color:white;"><small><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/75ac83_141f12dd5fc848b08fe41f79eded1260~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png/v1/fill/w_600,h_600,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/75ac83_141f12dd5fc848b08fe41f79eded1260~mv2_d_1208_1208_s_2.png" class="insurance-img"></small>Home </a></span>
          <span class="icon close"><a href="#" aria-label="Collapse Home & Renters" role="button">&#xe137;</a></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha, that was such a simple fix!  Now I feel dumb, because I should have known this... xD Thanks!!